# LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have stared my application successfully but after some time it will show this error logs on page reload. It happens several times and I have resolved it just deleting the target folder. I think this is not the permanent solution for this problem. Please help me for solving this problem.
I have also tried various solutions provided on this site but cant find a right solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.iGenius.iFinance.init.Initializer@46e14c8e]
May 31, 2017 12:47:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name []
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3926)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\Work\iFinance\iFin\target\classes\com\iGenius\iFinance\collectionentry\dao\CollectionEntryDAOImpl.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [D:\Work\iFinance\iFin\target\classes\com\iGenius\iFinance\collectionentry\dao\CollectionEntryDAOImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:281)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:219)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at com.iGenius.iFinance.init.Initializer.onStartup(Initializer.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [D:\Work\iFinance\iFin\target\classes\com\iGenius\iFinance\collectionentry\dao\CollectionEntryDAOImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
    ... 24 more

May 31, 2017 12:47:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [] is completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue, it would load on my local but not on CentOs. I deleted catalina.out, re-created it and then re-deployed my project and it got loaded fine.